# Asp.net Using ItemTemplate with SQL Server 2008 R2 database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using a gridview which displays names of people who are in a queue stored in a database. I have an ItemTemplate which generates "Checkin" and "Cancel" buttons for each person. Upon clicking one of those buttons I want to call a stored procedure which changes a column in my database making it so that row drops off in my gridview.

The problem I have is how to target an individual box in my C# so I know what I am passing to my stored procedure. I don't know how to connect that button to the information in the rest of the row.

```
<asp:GridView ID="Queue" runat="server"
               GridLines="None" SkinID="StatusGridSkin"
               AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="DisplayQueueSource"
               EmptyDataText="No Wait Time"
               CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="10"
               OnItemCommand="OnGridItemCommand" PropertName="Date" DataKeyField="ID">
    <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="Name"
                         ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="FirstName" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText=""
                         ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="LastName" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" DataFormatString="{0:hh:mm tt}"
                         HeaderText="Check In" HtmlEncode="False"
                         SortExpression="EndTime" />
         <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False"> 
             <ItemTemplate> 
                  <asp:Button ID="Checkin" runat="server"
                              CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Checkin"
                              Text="Check in"  CommandName="Checkin"/> 
             </ItemTemplate> 
         </asp:TemplateField> 
         <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False"> 
             <ItemTemplate> 
                 <asp:Button ID="Cancel" CommandName="MyButtonClick"
                             CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
                             runat="server" CausesValidation="false"
                             Text="Cancel"  CommandName="Cancel"/> 
             </ItemTemplate> 
         </asp:TemplateField> 
     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it. While a couple of tabs are off but it is better now I think.

Comment: It gives an error if I try to fix that. This is the best I can do.

Comment: I edited your markup code, just to show it without having to scroll, which makes it easier to read, at least to me.

Comment: Does the property "ID" exist on the items that are in your datasource?

Comment: Also, I noticed you are using a GridView. I'm using a DataGrid in my answer.. I'll check if that could cause any problem.

Comment: Hm, it seems as if the GridView control doesn't have the OnItemCommand, but rather the RowCommand event instead..

Comment: I see, thanks for all the replies. So will it work the same? Is it as simple as converting it to RowCommand? That must change the C# quite a bit.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, that should help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some markup to the grid;

```
OnRowCommand="OnGridRowCommand"
```

And add a CommandName to the button. Remember, if you are using one of the "built in" names like "Cancel", or "Delete", you should listen to the specific events instead, such as the Deleted event. The full list of recognized commands is available at msdn – [GridView.RowCommand event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx). Anyway, on the button, add the commandname and an argument.

```
CommandName="RemoveRow" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
```

Then, in code-behind

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnLoad(e);
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
        // on postback the grid is created thanks to the viewstate
        // that's why we don't bind it
        gridview.DataBind();
    }
}

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnInit(e);
    gridview.DataBinding += bindGridView;
}

protected void OnGridRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs args) {
    // The commandargument is set on the button, so a unique index for an item
    // should be used to identify it from the db.
    // in this case, commandargument is a string (not an int) so parse it
    int index = Int32.Parse((string)args.CommandArgument);
    switch (args.CommandName) {
        case "RemoveRow": {
                // remember, gridview.DataSource can be null here
                // so act on the database directly
                getSource().RemoveAt(index);
                gridview.DataBind();
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void bindGridView(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // set the source from the database
    gridview.DataSource = getSource();
}

// this represents the db
private List<ItemViewModel> source;
private IList<ItemViewModel> getSource() {
    if (source == null) {
        source = new List<ItemViewModel>();
        source.Add(new ItemViewModel("Karl"));
        source.Add(new ItemViewModel("Urban"));
        source.Add(new ItemViewModel("Bill"));
    }
    return source;
}

class ItemViewModel {
    private Guid id;
    public ItemViewModel(string name) {
        id = Guid.NewGuid();
        FirstName = name;
    }

    public Guid Id { get { return id; } }
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The part where the ItemIndex == -1, what is it checking for there? And also the variable "value", where is that value coming from? How does it now the [row][column] to grab?

Comment: I..can't remember why the check is there. I do remember that when I did this it got triggered with a negative index at a point, which triggered me to add the check.. :-S

Comment: The value is fetched from the DataKeys property of the grid, which is bound to "PropertyName" in the markup code. Normally you bind one item per row, so it's this value that is fetched when using the DataKeys property.

Comment: Oh I see, so I Just add "PropertyName" to one of my columns and that is what will get set to the value? That is awesome! Thank you.

Comment: Yes, so you should bind it to some id of the actual item, precisely!

Comment: To be more clear. You set the datasource on the grid to something. The type of items should have a property called PropertyName.

Comment: So I got everything going, except how can I get a button to call that function? I can't seem to get my button function to call the OnGridItemCommand.

Comment: The button shouldn't call the OnGridItemCommand. The grid does this automatically for every button in the templates. In other words, you only set the CommandName, not any command or click event.

Comment: ok I see now. This is really new to me. I think I got everything set up right. I edited the OP with the new markups I made. Can you check if they are correct? For some reason I am getting no value in the variable "value".